# My context requires identity mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am working on an application with two contexts, the first is IdentityModels, the second is GenericContext, I have migrations enabled for both contexts.

I can generate migrations of IdentityModels and there is no problem.

Instead, when generating migrations to GenericContext I have the following error:

[Error GenericContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5Qy.png)

This can be solved with the following lines in onModelCreating:

[Solution GenericContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s18w8.png)

This is not a valid solution because generating the GenericContext migrations creates the IdentityContext tables again as: [AspNetUserLogins], [AspNetUserRoles] and [AspNetRolePermisions]

what should I do?

Published my contexts:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

[Table("AspNetPermisions")]
public class Permision
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
}

[Table("AspNetRolePermisions")]
public class RolePermision
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public int PermisionId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PermisionId")]
    public virtual Permision Permision { get; set; }

}
[Table("AspNetRoles")]
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual string description { get; set; }
    public bool passive { get; set; }
    public virtual string type { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string createdIn { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string modifiedIn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("createdBy")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserCreate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("modifiedBy")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserModify { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RolePermision> RolePermisions { get; set; }
}

[Table("AspNetUserRoles")]
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public override string UserId { get; set; }
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("security");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermision>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.PermisionId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


class GenericContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericContext() : base("GenericConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermision>().HasKey(rp => new { rp.RoleId, rp.PermisionId }).ToTable("AspNetRolePermisions");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogsTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RolMenu> RolMenus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you need two different contexts?

Comment: I want to connect with different data managers (Sql, Postgres)

Comment: The AspNet Tables should be part of only one context: IdentityModels. The ApplicationUsers table is therefor not in place in the GenericContext, The table should be used for authentication only. If needed, create a user table that can be referenced by the identity.